# P-calendar - page starts on this element instead starting from top

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar, primeng

My problem is that the page automatically sets itself to the "p-calendar" element instead of starting at the top.

I have a 'mat-grid-list' and some 'mat-grid-tile' and when I go to that page it always sets to the calendar instead of the top.

```
    <mat-grid-tile
      [rowspan]="(isHandset$ | async) ? '1' : '2'"
      *ngIf="offerItem.calendarFlag"
    >
      <mat-card class="example-card">
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem"
            >Dostępność urządzenia:</mat-card-title
          >
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content
          style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center"
        >
          <div>
            <p-calendar
              [inline]="true"
              [selectOtherMonths]="true"
              [disabledDates]="disableDates"
              [showWeek]="!(isHandset$ | async)"
            ></p-calendar>
          </div>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions style="display: block">
          <div class="div-legend" *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)">
            <i class="bi bi-9-circle-fill week"></i><span>Numery tygodni</span>
          </div>

          <div class="div-legend">
            <i class="bi bi-9-circle-fill occupied"></i
            ><span>Termin niedostępny</span>
          </div>
        </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
```

I don't know what the problem is, I can't find a similar solution.